# unit testing sockets in java

Tags: java, sockets

I have a class which is a socket client and I am trying to unit test its methods.  The tests require that I start a socket server before each test so I use:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    if (myServerSocket == null) {
    Thread myThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            DataInputStream dis = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            try {
                ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(port);
                myServerSocket = myServer.accept();
                dis = new DataInputStream(myServerSocket.getInputStream());
                dos = new DataOutputStream(myServerSocket.getOutputStream());
                byte[] bytes = new byte[10];
                dis.read(bytes);
                boolean breakLoop = false;
                do {
                    if (new String(bytes).length() != 0) {
                        dos.writeBytes(serverMessage + "\n");
                        dos.flush();
                        breakLoop = true;
                        dos.writeBytes("</BroadsoftDocument>" + "\n");
                        dos.flush();
                    }
                } while (!breakLoop);
            } 
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    myThread.start();
    }
}
```

After each test I try to close the server socket so I can reopen the server socket for the next test:

```
@After
public void tearDown() throws IOException, BroadsoftSocketException {
    System.out.println("@After");
    if (myServerSocket != null) {
        myServerSocket.close();
        myServerSocket = null;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing.
            }
    }
}
```

However, I get "java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind" before each test starting with the second test.  I realize I am trying to use the same port for each test but shouldn't closing the socket free up the port?

Comment: Do you really need to connect to a real socket to test your code?  To test the code downstream of the socket, you could abstract it out so you pass in an `InputStream` and an `OutputStream` that are actually written to/read from your unit test.

Comment: I've seen sockets in unit tests before. It didn't end well - lots of random failures. Especially with delays like sleep(5000) added, because different people's machines will be slower at closing the sockets.
Is there no way to refactor the class so that its "SocketClient" parts are separate from its "Testable" logic parts? There's no benefit in testing the underlying java Socket code - we know that works. You only want to unit tests the bits of code that generate the messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quite possibly your socket is still in `TIME_WAIT` state when you attempt to reconnect it. I would recommend mocking such external dependencies, but if you really do find yourself wanting to continue using a real socket then try setting rebind options. In your setup function, instead of `ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket(port);` do :

```
final ServerSocket myServer = new ServerSocket();
myServer.setReuseAddress(true);
myServer.bind(new java.net.InetSocketAddress(port));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You already close your serversocket in "setUp" and you really should do it in a `finally` block.
2. The port may not be freed immediately. You can avoid this by setting the `ServerSocket`'s reuseAdress to `true`. See [setReuseAddress](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#setReuseAddress%28boolean%29).

And I second SimonC: maybe you are better off avoiding the socket in the first place.